# Can't activate django python environment in docker django application

Tags: django

Can't understand django command in docker application.

I am trying to run command which normally would work.

```
 source project/bin/activate
```

Which results in :

```
-bash: project/bin/activate: No such file or directory
```

The command would work in non docker django app for sure. Also tried :

```
 docker-compose run web  source project/bin/activate

docker-compose up source project/bin/activate
```

What is right command then?

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried, giving absolute path for the activate file. Something like this:

```
 ~/workspace/project/bin/activate
```

The above might actually work.

Comment: same result -bash: /Users/TheKotik/ticktock/project/bin/activate: No such file or directory

Comment: I created another virtual environment and it worked . So it's probably my fault

Comment: relative path is fine